# Convertfrom-JSON assistance

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-7.0, convertfrom-json

I am trying to put together a script to create a Microsoft Team from a JSON file. I am trying to understand Convertfrom-JSON and how I can pipe the object into creating a new team with channels and users. I can view the object by entering in $json.teams. why does $_.Displayname work? I know that is what is in the pipeline.

```
function New-MSteam {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [string]$TeamsFilePath
    )

    begin {
      
        #checking for Microsoft Teams Module
        Write-Verbose "Importing modules"
        $Module = Get-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -ListAvailable
        if ($Module.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Verbose "Installing MicrosoftTeams module"
            Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -AllowPrerelease -AllowClobber -Force
        }
  
        Connect-MicrosoftTeams

    }

    process {
        #Converting JSON
        $json = Get-Content  -Path c:\salest.json | ConvertFrom-Json
        $json.teams | ForEach-Object {
            $_.gettype().Team
        }

        #creating New team
        $NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $teams.DisplayName -Visibility $teams.Visibility
        $NewTeam.Users | ForEach-Object { $_.email
            Add-TeamUser -User $_.email -Role $_.Role -GroupId $NewTeam.GroupId
        }

        $Team.Channels | ForEach-Object
        New-TeamChannel -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -MembershipType $_.MembershipType -GroupId $NewTeam.GroupId
                      
    }
              
}

end {

}
```

```json
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "displayName": "IT Team",
            "visibility": "Public",
            "users": [
                {
                    "email": "admin@3q4kz.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "role": "Owner"
                },
                {
                    "email": "AlexW@3q4kz.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "role": "Member"
                },
                {
                    "email": "GradyA@3q4kz.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "role": "Member"
                }
            ],
            "channels": [
                {
                    "displayName": "Systems",
                    "membershipType": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Dev",
                    "membershipType": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Suport",
                    "membershipType": "Standard",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "email": "admin@3q44z.onmicrosoft.com",
                            "role": "Owner"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post a sample JSON file

Comment: `$_` references to each object being passed through the pipeline.

Comment: A really rough read of your code suggests that your `ForEach-Object` loop is emitting each team in the JSON object, but it's not getting assigned to anything. Then it makes reference to `$teams`, which doesn't look like it's actually assigned anywhere. Your second `ForEach-Object` loop references `$_.email` in the first statement, but then doesn't seem to do anything with it. Also, it looks like you're piping the new team's users into a loop to add the user to the team, which doesn't read right, as you just created it - it has no users?

Comment: Ran the source through VS Code's powershell formatter to help add clarity.

Comment: $_.gettype() comes with every variable.  I'm suspicious of $_.gettype().Team.

Comment: i added the json code.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole how do I assign the json object?

Comment: Is this the full JSON? or just a subset for an individual team?

Comment: it is the full json file

Comment: I've reformatted that, and am giving this a go in an answer.

Comment: Made a correction to the JSON as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this based on previous comments above. I had to do minor surgery on your JSON as it wasn't quite correct, please see above. This may not be completely correct, but perhaps it will get you closer:

```
function New-MSteam {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [string]$TeamsFilePath
    )

    begin {
      
        #checking for Microsoft Teams Module
        Write-Verbose "Importing modules"
        $Module = Get-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -ListAvailable
        if ($Module.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Verbose "Installing MicrosoftTeams module"
            Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -AllowPrerelease -AllowClobber -Force
        }
  
        Connect-MicrosoftTeams

    }

    process {
        # Convert JSON
        $json = Get-Content -Path c:\salest.json | ConvertFrom-Json

        # Iterate teams property in JSON
        $json.teams | ForEach-Object {
            # Create New team
            $NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -Visibility $_.Visibility
            
            # Iterate the users in JSON, adding them to the team just created
            $_.Users | ForEach-Object { 
                Add-TeamUser -User $_.email -Role $_.Role -GroupId $NewTeam.GroupId
            }

            # Iterate the channels in JSON
            $_.Channels | ForEach-Object {
                New-TeamChannel -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -MembershipType $_.MembershipType -GroupId $NewTeam.GroupId
            }                  
        }          
    }
}

end {

}
```

Comment: So that did create the team but did not add the users or create the channels.

Comment: TeamUser: 
Line |
   8 |  …             Add-TeamUser -User $_.email -Role $_.Role -GroupId $NewTe …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Error occurred while executing
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource 'admin@3q44kz.onmicrosoft.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 1d86ddb9-4fa0-475b-9baf-bdad73d4474d
  DateTimeStamp: 2021-12-03T15:59:34
HttpStatusCode: Request_ResourceNotFound

Comment: That error suggests your user doesn't exist in the current tenant. Is it somehow a guest user?

Comment: yes, I just figured this out. i was selected our prod tenant and not dev tenant. it works. Thank you!

Comment: So just putting the ForEach-Object goes through each item in the json?

Comment: Yep, goes through each item in the object to the left of the pipe. In your case, the teams property of the JSON, and then within each team, the users and the channels.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining. it makes sense now.